# X robots tag to noindex a single pdf file

Tags: seo, noindex, x-robots-tag

I need tour help. I have the need to noindex a single pdf file. I know that if i wanted to noindex all pdf files it would be great to use the x-robots tag

```
<FilesMatch ".pdf$">

Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet"

</FilesMatch>
```

What about if i want to leave all the other pdf indexed and i want to noindex just one pdf file? the path of the file woul be something like that [www.dominio.it/file.pdf](http://www.dominio.it/file.pdf)

I know that using the robot.txt is not a solution since it just prevent the crawling but not the indexing. Thx in advace to whoever will help me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.